# How do I load apt-key for Ignite with the new key install process?

Tags: installation, key, ignite, deprecated

- When following the steps for Ubuntu/Debian installon:

  - https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/deb-rpm
  - `sudo update` generates this warning:

    $ sudo apt update
    All packages are up to date.
    http://apache.org/dist/ignite/deb/dists/apache-ignite/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
- The man page shows a solution for a simple `wget` load

  - I'm not sure how that tracks against the instruction in the install step:

  $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0EE62FB37A00258D
- `wget` doesn't let me use the URL.

I'm hoping someone can recommend instructions for translating the above instruction into the up to date `apt` command to load a key.

The information to deal with deprecated command is in the man page:

```
$ man apt-key
 
DEPRECATION
    Except for using apt-key del in maintainer scripts, the use of apt-key is deprecated. This section 
    shows how to replace existing use of apt-key.

    If your existing use of apt-key add looks like this:

    wget -qO- https://myrepo.example/myrepo.asc | sudo apt-key add -

    Then you can directly replace this with (though note the recommendation below):

    wget -qO- https://myrepo.example/myrepo.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/myrepo.asc

    Make sure to use the "asc" extension for ASCII armored keys and the "gpg" extension for the binary OpenPGP format (also known as "GPG key public ring"). The binary OpenPGP format
    works for all apt versions, while the ASCII armored format works for apt version >= 1.4.

    Recommended: Instead of placing keys into the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d directory, you can place them anywhere on your filesystem by using the Signed-By option in your sources.list and
    pointing to the filename of the key. See sources.list(5) for details. Since APT 2.4, /etc/apt/keyrings is provided as the recommended location for keys not managed by packages. When
    using a deb822-style sources.list, and with apt version >= 2.4, the Signed-By option can also be used to include the full ASCII armored keyring directly in the sources.list without
    an additional file.
```

How to I get this:  `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0EE62FB37A00258D`, into the file as shown in the manual?

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't specifically an Apache Ignite issue, I sympathize with your difficulty.

The documented apt-key command syntax uses a PGP key exchange server protocol URL (eg. "hkp://..") but you may not know that Horowitz Key Protocol (HKP) is based on HTTP. If you change the hkp url to http (note that https will not always work, so use http explicitly), a browser will render a search form allowing you to enter a keychain ID, like the given '0EE62FB37A00258D' ID.

```
http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/
```

The page with search results will yield a link to a MIME encoded PGP public key.

```
http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x390ef70bb1ea12b2773962950ee62fb37a00258d
```

The search term in this URL is a PGP fingerprint for the public key you want. The key ID in the documentation is a truncation of the least significant bits of the fingerprint, and so the key ID substring can also be used to search and get the key.

```
https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x0EE62FB37A00258D
```

Please try this URL as modeled in the apt-key deprecation warning in lieu of the `https://myrepo.example/myrepo.asc` example.